# Re-asking a question

Tags: discussion, deletion, bumping

I asked [Why $p$-adically interpolate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320939/why-p-adically-interpolate) while I wasn't signed in - this unknown user is me. Although this is a pretty general question, and should probably be easy to answer by an expert in that field, it has never received answer nor comment. Is it acceptable to ask this question again, to raise awareness? I don't want to put a bounty on it since I've never done that before and I'm not sure it's worth it - I would just like a little motivating paragraph about why this is interesting or useful. Anyway, I no longer have access to this account and couldn't accept an answer on it.

It doesn't seem like there is any other way to bump a question, though.

Comment: Have you tried to [merge your accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge)?

Comment: @robjohn I never made that into a registered account - it was probably asked on a university computer, where I don't like to sign in for security reasons

Comment: You should still be able to merge the accounts, either using that page, or contacting the staff.

Comment: @robjohn I don't think that works. I never logged in, I just went on stackexchange and used a fake email, probably asdf@asdf.com or something. I don't like to use my real email on public-access computers..

Answer (score 3):

The question looks like it should be okay. It may be that it needs a different (yet appropriate) tag to attract people who are watching that tag or a bounty to interest people.  This happens. However, it is not encouraged to ask the same question again.

Comment: This is a good idea - I've added some tags which seem relevant. If nothing happens I guess I discuss this with my adviser (although I'm kind of embarrassed to, since this is my thesis topic, and I still don't quite know why it's useful)

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't seen the question, but now that I have, I posted an answer.  In general, making an edit is one way to bump the question.  When questions only stay on the front-page for a short time, it is easy for them to be missed by people with the relevant expertise.